# R Map differing functions to nested list

Tags: r, list, nested, mapply

Using base R, I would like to apply a *different* function to each element of a nested list. I know how to apply the *same* function to a nested list with

> lapply(list, lapply, function).

However, I'm looking for an elegant way to apply a *different* function to each element. The code below works, but I find the use of

> function(x) lapply(x, function(x))

is ugly so I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution.

```
Data <- list(
    Panel1 = list(
        DF1 = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10)),
        DF2 = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10))
    ),
    Panel2 = list(
        DF1 = data.frame(C = rnorm(10), D = rnorm(10)),
        DF2 = data.frame(C = rnorm(10), D = rnorm(10))
        )
)

Fns <- list(
    function(x) lapply(x, function(x) x[1:5, c("B", "A")]),
    function(x) lapply(x, function(x) x[1:5, c("D", "C")])
)

Map(function(a, b) b(a), Data, Fns)
```

Comment: sounds like the `?compose` function in the `purrr` package may be helpful for your case.

Comment: You find `Map` ugly?

Comment: This is another way to do it but I don't think it is more elegant `lapply(1:2,function(f){
  funx <- Fns[[f]]
  funx(Data[[f]])
})`

Comment: I have two questions: (1) you want to apply different functions over a nested list, but your example uses the same function (subsetting with []) and only the arguments differ. Do you want to do the latter or the former? (2) There might be more concise approaches using the tidyverse, but if I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a Base R approach, right?

Comment: Further, if you want to apply the same function with different arguments, the next question would be: can the arguments be chosen by a function. Then also a nested lapply might work:  sub_fn <- function(ls, x)                           lapply(ls, function(x) x[1:5, colnames(x)])

lapply(Data, sub_fn)

Comment: (1) The former, totally different functions. (2) Yes, base R. (3) No, the arguments cannot be chosen by the function. My list elements are often data.frames that are similar within their own list but different outside of it. Lastly, Map(function(a, b) b(a), Data, Fns) works great on non-nested lists. I use it all the time. Maybe Map(function(x) Map(function(a, b) b(a), x, Fns)) will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I can answer my own question. This works and I think it is as simple as you can get with base R.

```
Data <- list(
    Panel1 = list(
        DF1 = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10)),
        DF2 = data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10))
    ),
    Panel2 = list(
        DF1 = data.frame(C = rnorm(10), D = rnorm(10)),
        DF2 = data.frame(C = rnorm(10), D = rnorm(10))
    )
)

Fns <- list(
    function(x) x[1:5, c("B", "A")],
    function(x) x[1:5, c("D", "C")]
)

Map(function(a, b) lapply(a, b), Data, Fns)
```